# Why are unused type parameters on Rust structs considered an error and not a warning?

Tags: generics, rust, compiler-construction

Before somebody marks this as a duplicate, I know ***how*** to fix it (and that has been answered already), but I'd like to understand ***why*** this limitation exists, and I found no answer on here or in the Rust docs.

For example, I wrote something that goes something like this:

```rust
struct ItemList<T> {
  items: Vec<T>
}
impl<T> ItemList<T> {
  fn getFirstItem(&self) -> Link<T> { Link { position: 0 } }
}

struct Link<T> {
  position: usize
}
impl<T> Link<T> {
  fn getFromList<'a>(&self, list: &'a ItemList<T>) -> &'a T {
    &list.items[self.position]
  }
}
```

But rustc rejects my code with this error:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 | struct Link<T> {
  |             ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
  = help: if you intended `T` to be a const parameter, use `const T: usize` instead

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0392`.
```

**Why is that an error and not a warning**? The type parameters only reduce the performance during compile time (if I understood it correctly), so why would you enforce removing it or using a PhantomData marker? Does it have some implications that I missed?

Comment: In what way is `struct Foo<T>;` parameterised by `T`?  In particular: is `Foo` covariant, contravariant or invariant over `T` (see [the Rustonomicon chapter on variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html))?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a variance issue.

Rust determines the variance of a type parameter by its usage. If the type is not used, Rust cannot know the variance of the type.

The [Rustonomicon has a chapter about variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

Answer (score 5):

Adding to what @mcarton said, this was not this way from the beginning: Rust used to infer unused generic parameters are bivariant. This changed in 2014 (before Rust 1.0). The motivation is explained in [the RFC](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/rfcs/blob/no-bivariance/active/0000-remove-bivariance.md):

> ## Motivation
>
> Today, variance inference for lifetimes includes the notion of *bivariance* -- which essentially amounts to unconstrained. In principle, this can have some use, but in practice it tends to be a vector for bugs. In fact, there is no known Rust code that *intentionally* uses bivariance (though there seems to be plenty that does so accidentally and incorrectly). This RFC proposes that we simply make an inference result of bivariance an error.
>
> As an example of where this comes up, imagine a `struct` with a "phantom" lifetime parameter, meaning one that is not actually *used* in the fields of the `struct` itself. One example of such a type is `Items`, the vector iterator:
>
> ```rust
> struct Items<'vec, T> {
>     x: *mut T
> }
> ```
>
> Here the lifetime `'vec` is intended to represent the lifetime of the vector being iterated over and hence to prevent the iterator from outliving the container. However, because it does not appear in the body of `Items` at all, the compiler would currently consider it irrelevant to subtyping. This means that you could convert from a `Items<'a, T>` to a `Items<'static, T>`, causing the iterator to outlive the container it is iterating over.
>
> To prevent this scenario, the `actual` definition of the iterator in the standard library uses a *marker* type. The marker type informs the compiler that, although `'vec` does not appear to be used, it should act *as if* it were. For example, `Items` might be modified as follows:
>
> ```rust
> struct Items<'vec, T> {
>     x: *mut T,
>     marker: marker::CovariantType<&'vec T>,
> }
> ```
>
> the `CovariantType` marker basically informs the compiler that it should act "as though" a reference of type `&'vec T` were a member of Items, even thought it is not. Another equivalent option here would be `ContravariantLifetime`.
>
> Currently, the user must know to insert these markers or else silently get the wrong behavior. This RFC makes it an error to have a type or lifetime parameter that is not (transitively) used somewhere in the type. Nothing else is changed.

The code is pretty old (e.g. `CovariantType` and `ContravariantLifetime` were replaced by `PhantomData`), but the concept still applies.